# How to group data correctly to get a tree structure?

Tags: json, go, hierarchy

In golang application I make query to such table:

```
| ID        | AGG_YEAR | AGG_MONTH | GENDER | AGE_RANGE | INCOME_RANGE | TOTAL |
|-----------|----------|-----------|--------|-----------|--------------|-------|
| 107502389 | 2019     | 7         | F      | 18_29     | 1000_2000    | 15    |
| 107502389 | 2019     | 7         | F      | 18_29     | 2000_4000    | 42    |
| 107502389 | 2019     | 7         | F      | 30_44     | 1000_2000    | 25    |
| 107502389 | 2019     | 7         | F      | 30_44     | 2000_4000    | 63    |
| 107502389 | 2019     | 7         | M      | 18_29     | 1000_2000    | 30    |
| 107502389 | 2019     | 7         | M      | 18_29     | 2000_4000    | 18    |
| 107502389 | 2019     | 7         | M      | 30_44     | 1000_2000    | 36    |
| 107502389 | 2019     | 7         | M      | 30_44     | 2000_4000    | 19    |
```

This table stores information about the total number of males and females with a certain wage level in a certain month. Usually, after a query to the database, each record is parsed separately one by one:

```
type Entry struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    AggYear int `json:"agg_year"`
    AggMonth int `json:"agg_month"`
    Gender string `json:"gender"`
    AgeRange string `json:"age_range"`
    IncomeRange string `json:"income_range"`
    Total int `json:"total"`
}

var entries []Entry

rows, err := database.Query("***"); if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    var entry Entry

    if err = rows.Scan(&entry.ID, &entry.AggMethod, &entry.AggYear, &entry.AggMonth, &entry.Gender, &entry.AgeRange, &entry.IncomeRange, &entry.Total); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    entries = append(entries, entry)
}

type IncomeDetails struct {
    IncomeRange string `json:"income_range"`
    Total int `json:"total"`
}

type AgeDetails struct {
    AgeRange string `json:"age_range"`
    Details []IncomeDetails `json:"details"`
}

type GenderDetails struct {
    Gender string `json:"gender"`
    Details []AgeDetails `json:"details"`
}

type EntryDetails struct {
    AggYear int `json:"agg_year"`
    AggMonth int `json:"agg_month"`
    Details []GenderDetails `json:"details"`
}

type DataEntry struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    Details []EntryDetails `json:"details"`
}

var entryDetails []EntryDetails

i:= 0
for i < len(entries) {
    var genderDetails []GenderDetails
    aggYear := entries[i].AggYear
    aggMonth := entries[i].AggMonth

    for aggYear == entries[i].AggYear && aggMonth == entries[i].AggMonth {
        gender := entries[i].Gender
        var ageDetails []AgeDetails
        for gender == entries[i].Gender {
            ageRange := entries[i].AgeRange
            var incomeDetails []IncomeDetails

            for ageRange == entries[i].AgeRange && gender == entries[i].Gender { // <- runtime error: index out of range
                incomeDetail := IncomeDetails{entries[i].IncomeRange, entries[i].Total}
                incomeDetails = append(incomeDetails, incomeDetail)
                i++
            }
            ageDetail := AgeDetails{entries[i-1].AgeRange, incomeDetails}
            ageDetails = append(ageDetails, ageDetail)
            i++
        }
        genderDetail := GenderDetails{entries[i-1].Gender, ageDetails}
        genderDetails = append(genderDetails, genderDetail)
        i++
    }
    entryDetail := EntryDetails{entries[i-1].AggYear, entries[i-1].AggMonth, genderDetails}
    entryDetails = append(entryDetails, entryDetail)
    i++
}
```

I want to know the best way to group the following values as in the example below? I want to understand the sequence of actions. I will be grateful for any help.

```
[
    {
        "id": 107502389,
        "details": [
            {
                "agg_year": 2019,
                "agg_month": 7,
                "details": [
                    {
                        "gender": "F",
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "age_range": "18_29",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "income_range": "1000_2000",
                                        "total": "15"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "income_range": "2000_4000",
                                        "total": "42"
                                    },
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "age_range": "30_44",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "income_range": "1000_2000",
                                        "total": "25"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "income_range": "2000_4000",
                                        "total": "63"
                                    },
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "gender": "M",
                        "details": [
                            {
                                "age_range": "18_29",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "income_range": "1000_2000",
                                        "total": "30"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "income_range": "2000_4000",
                                        "total": "18"
                                    },
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "age_range": "30_44",
                                "details": [
                                    {
                                        "income_range": "1000_2000",
                                        "total": "36"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "income_range": "2000_4000",
                                        "total": "19"
                                    },
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: By iterating over them and organizing them however you need them. Have you made any attempt at this at all? Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: @Adrian everything I've tried has been unsuccessful, so I'm trying to understand the sequence of actions. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If you've tried something that didn't work, you should show that code and describe what specific problem(s) you ran into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, I would be updating the Structure according to the response i want. For example in your case it would be :

```
type DataEntry struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    Details []EntryDetails `json:"details"`
}

type EntryDetails struct { 
    AggYear int `json:"agg_year"`
    AggMonth int `json:"agg_month"`
    Details []GenderDetails `json:"details"`
}

type GenderDetails struct {
    Gender string `json:"gender"`
    Details []AgeDetails `json:"details"`
} 

type AgeDetails struct {
    AgeRange string `json:"age_range"`
    Details []IncomeDetails `json:"details"`
}

type IncomeDetails struct { 
    IncomeRange string `json:"income_range"`
    Total int `json:"total"`
}
```

Dividing your code into smaller parts is always easier to read and maintain.

Next part to add the details to the struct : you should Query your code according to the requirements to fill the struct one by one. For example: getID-'Entry struct' first, then getAggYear & getAggMonth for the ID-'EntryDetails struct' and so one.

You can find the full working program here : https://play.golang.org/p/_pdb5y9Wd-O

Enjoy !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please describe in more detail the part where we need to fill the struct one by one? It is not quite clear to me.

Comment: Can you see the edited post. Also we would still need the struct that you are using just to read the table first , this way would be faster than directly reading into the DataEntry Struct

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to test your code right now. Instead of `while` loop I used `for` loop. Unfortunately, it raises an error: `http: panic serving [::1]:12997: runtime error: index out of range`. This condition causes an error: `ageRange == entries[i].AgeRange && gender == entries[i].Gender`. Check my post again please for more details. Also as you have noticed I need array of `DataEntry` struct as a final result cause there can be different ID. For that's why I need one more loop, right?

Comment: Okay so as i is getting incremented we need to check for the length at every condition and i did fix the data entry struct condition too . Please have a look at the edited function

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to test your last edited code right now but unfortunately the problem in the same part as in the last comment. Also what exactly makes this part of code `e := DataEntry{entries[i-1].ID, entryDetails}`?

Comment: Also why you use `while` although golang don't have such statement?

Comment: you are correct i was just working on the logic ! let me have a look again .

Comment: Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: I have added the link to the golang playground, which is totally working, so enjoy !